# Error to install openvpn on debian

Tags: linux, debian, vpn, openvpn

I'm on Debian 7 and I had an error to install openvpn:

```
aurelien@ns22895:~$ sudo apt-get install openvpn
[sudo] password for aurelien: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  liblzo2-2 libpkcs11-helper1
Suggested packages:
  resolvconf
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  liblzo2-2 libpkcs11-helper1 openvpn
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 611 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,450 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Get:1 http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net/debian/ wheezy/main liblzo2-2 amd64 2.06-1 [57.7 kB]
Get:2 http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net/debian/ wheezy/main libpkcs11-helper1 amd64 1.09-1 [50.2 kB]
Get:3 http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net/debian/ wheezy/main openvpn amd64 2.2.1-8+deb7u2 [503 kB]
Fetched 611 kB in 0s (2,693 kB/s)
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package liblzo2-2:amd64.
(Reading database ... 38810 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking liblzo2-2:amd64 (from .../liblzo2-2_2.06-1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libpkcs11-helper1:amd64.
Unpacking libpkcs11-helper1:amd64 (from .../libpkcs11-helper1_1.09-1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package openvpn.
Unpacking openvpn (from .../openvpn_2.2.1-8+deb7u2_amd64.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up liblzo2-2:amd64 (2.06-1) ...
Setting up libpkcs11-helper1:amd64 (1.09-1) ...
Setting up openvpn (2.2.1-8+deb7u2) ...
[ ok ] Restarting virtual private network daemon.:.
insserv: warning: script 'K02firewall' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'firewall' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'stop-firewall' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop between service monit and stop-firewall if stopped
insserv:  loop involving service stop-firewall at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service monit at depth 1
insserv: Stopping stop-firewall depends on monit and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing openvpn (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 openvpn
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Now when I use apt-get, there is an error, example with apt-get upgrade:

```
aurelien@ns22895:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  icedtea-6-jre-cacao icedtea-6-jre-jamvm openjdk-6-jre-headless
  openjdk-6-jre-lib
The following packages will be upgraded:
  base-files dpkg dpkg-dev jenkins libapache2-mod-php5 libdpkg-perl libxml2
  linux-libc-dev php-pear php5 php5-cli php5-common php5-curl php5-dev php5-gd
  php5-mcrypt php5-mysql tzdata tzdata-java
19 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 76.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 179 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Get:1 http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net/debian/ wheezy/main base-files amd64 7.1wheezy5 [78.7 kB]
Get:2 http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net/debian/ wheezy/main libxml2 amd64 2.8.0+dfsg1-7+nmu3 [904 kB]
Get:3 http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/main dpkg amd64 1.16.14 [2,651 kB]
Get:4 http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net/debian/ wheezy/main tzdata-java all 2014a-0wheezy1 [131 kB]
Get:5 http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net/debian/ wheezy/main tzdata all 2014a-0wheezy1 [445 kB]
Get:6 http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net/debian/ wheezy/main php5-cli amd64 5.4.4-14+deb7u9 [2,559 kB]
Get:7 http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net/debian/ wheezy/main libapache2-mod-php5 amd64 5.4.4-14+deb7u9 [2,669 kB]
Get:8 http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/main dpkg-dev all 1.16.14 [1,352 kB]
Get:9 http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net/debian/ wheezy/main php5-mysql amd64 5.4.4-14+deb7u9 [80.9 kB]
Get:10 http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/main libdpkg-perl all 1.16.14 [956 kB]
Get:11 http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net/debian/ wheezy/main php5-mcrypt amd64 5.4.4-14+deb7u9 [16.1 kB]
Get:12 http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net/debian/ wheezy/main php5-gd amd64 5.4.4-14+deb7u9 [35.7 kB]
Get:13 http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net/debian/ wheezy/main php5-curl amd64 5.4.4-14+deb7u9 [29.2 kB]
Get:14 http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian/ binary/ jenkins 1.561 [62.1 MB]        
Get:15 http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net/debian/ wheezy/main php5-common amd64 5.4.4-14+deb7u9 [591 kB]
Get:16 http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net/debian/ wheezy/main linux-libc-dev amd64 3.2.57-3 [823 kB]
Get:17 http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net/debian/ wheezy/main php-pear all 5.4.4-14+deb7u9 [369 kB]
Get:18 http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net/debian/ wheezy/main php5 all 5.4.4-14+deb7u9 [1,030 B]
Get:19 http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net/debian/ wheezy/main php5-dev amd64 5.4.4-14+deb7u9 [498 kB]
Fetched 76.3 MB in 7s (10.0 MB/s)                                               
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 38966 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace base-files 7.1wheezy4 (using .../base-files_7.1wheezy5_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement base-files ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up base-files (7.1wheezy5) ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/debian_version ...
(Reading database ... 38966 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace dpkg 1.16.12 (using .../dpkg_1.16.14_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement dpkg ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up dpkg (1.16.14) ...
(Reading database ... 38966 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace libxml2:amd64 2.8.0+dfsg1-7+nmu2 (using .../libxml2_2.8.0+dfsg1-7+nmu3_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libxml2:amd64 ...
Preparing to replace tzdata-java 2013i-0wheezy1 (using .../tzdata-java_2014a-0wheezy1_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement tzdata-java ...
Preparing to replace tzdata 2013i-0wheezy1 (using .../tzdata_2014a-0wheezy1_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement tzdata ...
Setting up tzdata (2014a-0wheezy1) ...

Current default time zone: 'Europe/Paris'
Local time is now:      Fri May  2 09:48:25 CEST 2014.
Universal Time is now:  Fri May  2 07:48:25 UTC 2014.
Run 'dpkg-reconfigure tzdata' if you wish to change it.

(Reading database ... 38966 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace php5-cli 5.4.4-14+deb7u8 (using .../php5-cli_5.4.4-14+deb7u9_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement php5-cli ...
Preparing to replace libapache2-mod-php5 5.4.4-14+deb7u8 (using .../libapache2-mod-php5_5.4.4-14+deb7u9_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libapache2-mod-php5 ...
Preparing to replace php5-mysql 5.4.4-14+deb7u8 (using .../php5-mysql_5.4.4-14+deb7u9_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement php5-mysql ...
Preparing to replace php5-mcrypt 5.4.4-14+deb7u8 (using .../php5-mcrypt_5.4.4-14+deb7u9_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement php5-mcrypt ...
Preparing to replace php5-gd 5.4.4-14+deb7u8 (using .../php5-gd_5.4.4-14+deb7u9_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement php5-gd ...
Preparing to replace php5-curl 5.4.4-14+deb7u8 (using .../php5-curl_5.4.4-14+deb7u9_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement php5-curl ...
Preparing to replace php5-common 5.4.4-14+deb7u8 (using .../php5-common_5.4.4-14+deb7u9_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement php5-common ...
Preparing to replace dpkg-dev 1.16.12 (using .../dpkg-dev_1.16.14_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement dpkg-dev ...
Preparing to replace libdpkg-perl 1.16.12 (using .../libdpkg-perl_1.16.14_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libdpkg-perl ...
Preparing to replace linux-libc-dev:amd64 3.2.54-2 (using .../linux-libc-dev_3.2.57-3_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement linux-libc-dev:amd64 ...
Preparing to replace php-pear 5.4.4-14+deb7u8 (using .../php-pear_5.4.4-14+deb7u9_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement php-pear ...
Preparing to replace php5 5.4.4-14+deb7u8 (using .../php5_5.4.4-14+deb7u9_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement php5 ...
Preparing to replace php5-dev 5.4.4-14+deb7u8 (using .../php5-dev_5.4.4-14+deb7u9_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement php5-dev ...
Preparing to replace jenkins 1.560 (using .../archives/jenkins_1.561_all.deb) ...
[ ok ] Stopping Jenkins Continuous Integration Server: jenkins.
Unpacking replacement jenkins ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up openvpn (2.2.1-8+deb7u2) ...
[ ok ] Restarting virtual private network daemon.:.
insserv: warning: script 'K02firewall' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'firewall' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'stop-firewall' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop between service monit and stop-firewall if stopped
insserv:  loop involving service stop-firewall at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service monit at depth 1
insserv: Stopping stop-firewall depends on monit and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing openvpn (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up libxml2:amd64 (2.8.0+dfsg1-7+nmu3) ...
Setting up tzdata-java (2014a-0wheezy1) ...
Setting up php5-common (5.4.4-14+deb7u9) ...
Setting up php5-cli (5.4.4-14+deb7u9) ...
Setting up libapache2-mod-php5 (5.4.4-14+deb7u9) ...
[ ok ] Reloading web server config: apache2.
Setting up php5-mysql (5.4.4-14+deb7u9) ...
Setting up php5-mcrypt (5.4.4-14+deb7u9) ...
Setting up php5-gd (5.4.4-14+deb7u9) ...
Setting up php5-curl (5.4.4-14+deb7u9) ...
Setting up libdpkg-perl (1.16.14) ...
Setting up dpkg-dev (1.16.14) ...
Setting up linux-libc-dev:amd64 (3.2.57-3) ...
Setting up php-pear (5.4.4-14+deb7u9) ...
Setting up php5 (5.4.4-14+deb7u9) ...
Setting up php5-dev (5.4.4-14+deb7u9) ...
Setting up jenkins (1.561) ...
insserv: warning: script 'K02firewall' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'firewall' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'stop-firewall' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop between service monit and stop-firewall if stopped
insserv:  loop involving service stop-firewall at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service monit at depth 1
insserv: Stopping stop-firewall depends on monit and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing jenkins (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for libapache2-mod-php5 ...
[ ok ] Reloading web server config: apache2.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 openvpn
 jenkins
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I fix this error and install openvpn?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is an init script installed (`/etc/init.d/firewall`) which is not default in Debian and has some syntax errors in the metadata contained within the script (LSB headers).

You can try removing the references to the script and move it temporarily to another directory and then install OpenVPN.

```
sudo update-rc.d firewall disable
     # Or if that doesn't work:
     sudo rm /etc/rc*.d/K02firewall
sudo mv /etc/init.d/firewall /root/firewall
sudo mv /etc/init.d/stop-firewall /root/firewall
```

There might be other references in `/etc/` as well. You can find them with:

```
sudo find /etc -name "*firewall*" 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: Thank you it worked!

The /etc/init.d/firewall and /etc/init.d/stop-firewall files are mine.

It seems that I needed to add the "INIT INFO" comment block.

As I don't know the values to put, I let them blank and I don't have the "missing LSB tags and overrides" error for "update-rc.d firewall defaults".

Is it right?

Comment: You should read about the format of the metadata used in Debian init files. You should specify the dependencies for your firewall there (for example, network must be up before configuring firewall). Also, you should combine those two scripts and use `start` and `stop` parameters to the script to start / stop the services. That way the scripts would work like they are specified to work.